# Can I bind xib file to view controller via IBOutlet?

Tags: swift, xib, iboutlet

I have a `ViewController`, and I want to dynamically load different `UIView` based on `UISegmentedControl`.I designed 3 `UIViews` in **xib** file. And I have set their File's Owner's Custtom class to my view controller name in Identify Inspector.After I connect my xib to view controller code via `IBOutlet`, I add the connected view via "`addSubview(view)`" method in `viewDidLoad` method. But When I run it, the compiler tells me that the connected view is **null**.

Comment: Need more information. Do you mean to say you created three xib files each containing one view, or that you created one xib file that contains three views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making three different xib files. Make one xib file with all three views in it, plus a fourth "default" view. Each view should be connected to a different IBOutlet in your class.

Then in your `viewDidLoad` figure out which view you want to display and `addSubview` it to your default view.
[image]

Comment: Not working...it just says the optional view is nil.And if use UINib to load it ,it works.    lazy var view1: UIView! = UINib(nibName: "CreatureConciergeTab", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView

Comment: Your "default" view must be attached to the view controllers `view` IBOutlet.